# pg_dumpall is dumping only "postgres" database, not all databases

Tags: postgresql, dump

Strangely, on one of our server, pg_dumpall, when executed by cron, only dumps "postgres" database, instead of all databases.

But when executing it from command line, it works.

I suspect it must be due to some environment variable, but I don't know where it may come from.

Of course I can provide more information if needed, but I don't know what to give more, because I don't exactly know the source of this strange problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the cron script is executing either

1. as a different user.
2. with different arguments.
3. running a different program altogether.

If you're on Ubuntu or Debian make sure you're using the one in your path directly, you may have one in `/usr/lib` and one in `/usr/bin`

Comment: Sorry to come back 2 yeas later but it happens again...

Strangely :

1. It is the same user (postgres)
2. Exact same arguments (copy and paste from script executed by crontab)
3. The same program as I directly call "/usr/bin/pg_dumpall"